# Mongodb shadring based on collection name

Tags: mongodb, load-balancing, sharding

I would like to use sharding based on the name of the collection in mongoDB.
I m storing timeseries from different sensors and each (day,sensor) pair is assigned on one collection. So I create nDays x nSensor new collections every day. I m basically using the table name as a main key to speed up things.

I ve read that mongoDb sharding is done at the collection level. My understanding is that documents from the same collection could be on 2 different shards. I don't want that behavior.

I d like all documents of a given collection to be stored on the same shard but I want mongoDb to automatically distribute collections over my N shards. I could come up with some logic on my end to distribute my data over N different Dbs based on collection name but I want the load balancing to be done automatically and scale seemlesly.

Is it possible?

I saw this document

http://www.askasya.com/post/taggedcollectionbalancing/

But I m not sure how I can use the collection name as a tag.